# Why does ST AM_PWS_REPORTING is not filtering correctly?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, portfolio

I'm trying to run the ST AM_PWS_REPORTING, this consists in taking the info of a report in PWS and exporting it to excel through the ST, but when I do it the info in excel is inconsistent with the info of PWS, does anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by changing the Portfolio Name in your ST, and instead put the Grouping ID displayed in the Portfolio Hierarchy window.

I hope this helps!